# Somar determinada coluna por JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma tabela que vai adicionando de acordo com o usuário, ou seja ele pode inserir ou excluir a linha da tabela a qualquer momento, e eu queria um código que somasse uma determinada coluna (no caso ela soma todos os valores dos produtos e me informa o valor total da compra).

```js
// adicionando nova linha na tabela
var newRow = jQuery(
  '<tr>' +
  '<td id="prod">' + produto + '</td>' +
  '<td id="un">' + unidade + '</td>' +
  '<td id="vol">' + volume + '</td>' +
  '<td id="qtd">' + quantidade + '</td>' +
  '<td id="peso">' + peso + '</td>' +
  '<td id="uni">R$ ' + unitario.replace(".", ",").replace("00", "") + '</td>' +
  '<td id="tot">' + currencyFormatted((unitario * quantidade), 'R$') + '</td>' +
  '<td id="desc">R$ 0,00</td>' +
  '<td id="liq">' + currencyFormatted((unitario * quantidade), 'R$') + '</td>' +
  '<td><button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">-</button></td>' +
  '</tr>'
);
jQuery('table.table-bordered').append(newRow);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered"></table>
```

Comment: Seria interessante você postar o que você já tentou fazer ou qual erro está ocasionando o problema. Consegue [editar a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/273212/edit) e inserir essas informações?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de tudo, você está usando nas colunas o atributo `id` com valores fixos. Isso na prática, ao adicionar a 2ª linha, vai criar elementos com `id` repetido, o que não é correto. Troque eles de `id` por `class`, que não terá esse problema.

Dito isso, você pode pegar todos os elementos de determinada classe, no caso poderia ser a classe `liq` nesse seu exemplo, fazer o parse do valor formatado (provavelmente se está usando uma biblioteca com essa função `currencyFormatted`, pode haver outra função para fazer o inverso), e somar tudo.

Veja se este exemplo ajuda você, a função que faz o que você quer chamei de `updateSum`:

```js
$(function() {
  var nItem = 1;
  function newItem(ev) {
    console.log('newItem');
    var value = getRandomIntInclusive(1000, 10000);
    var qty = getRandomIntInclusive(1, 5);
    var total = value * qty;
    var item = {
      'name': 'Item ' + nItem++,
      'value': (value / 100).toFixed(2),
      'qty': qty,
      'total': (qty * total / 100).toFixed(2)
    };
    var html = '<tr>';
    for(var k in item) {
      html += '<td class="' + k + '">' + item[k] + '</td>';
    }
    html += '<td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-label="Remove Item"></span></button>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('table.table-bordered tbody').append(html);
    updateSum();
  }
  function removeItem(ev) {
    console.log('removeItem');
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    updateSum();
  }
  function updateSum() {
    console.log('updateSum');
    var total = 0;
    $('tbody .total').each(function (idx, el) {
      total += parseFloat($(el).html());
    })
    $('#sum').html(total.toFixed(2));
  }
  function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
  $("#new-item").on('click', newItem);
  $(document).on('click', '.remove-item', removeItem);
});
```

```css
th.name {
  width: 50%;
}
th.value {
  width: 15%;
}
th.qty {
  width: 15%;
}
th.total {
  width: 15%;
}
th.remove-action {
  width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container-fluid'>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="new-item">New item</button>
  <hr />

  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class='name'>Name</th>
        <th class='value'>Value</th>
        <th class='qty'>Qty</th>
        <th class='total'>Total</th>
        <th class='remove-action'>-</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th colspan='3' class='text-right'>Sum</th>
        <th id="sum">-</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  
</div>
```